# overwriting maven skip tests by default

Tags: maven, junit, junit4

I have a maven with this pom.xml

```
..
<properties>
        <!-- Skip tests by default-->
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>

        <!-- Build complete package by default; use -Dskip.npm.install=true -Dskip.npm.build=true when working on backend code -->
        <skip.npm.install>false</skip.npm.install>
        <skip.npm.build>false</skip.npm.build>

        <node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
        <springboot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <kerberos.version>1.0.1.RELEASE</kerberos.version>
    </properties>
..
```

I run this command to avoid skipping tests, but the tests are not run

> mvn test -Dmaven.test.skip=false

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to skip test or run tests ?

Try mvn test -X for debug output.

Comment: I am trying to run the tests

Comment: Then you should simply remove the property `skipTests` from your pom file ...and control this by command as @JF Meier already explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user property is `skipTests`, so use

```
mvn test -DskipTests=false
```